# Using jest to test React, my project has to log in first to test, and setupFile does not support asynchronous. Do I have to do login in every test?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

my question is about using jest to test React, my project has to log in first to test, and setupFile does not support asynchronous. Do I have to do login in every test? It's a waste of time

Comment: You should look into mocking aspects of the application. Ideally if you are testing a functionality of your application, it should not have to know anything about login/session, etc, unless it directly impacts that functionality.  You should be able to mock dependencies until you are left with tests that focus on small pieces of functionality. Because you really don't want to be testing login each time, you want to be testing functionality.

Comment: thank you！I used Google's poppeteer to open a headless browser to simulate user operation. It's necessary to log in.